# QT display image with Qlabel in layouts not working

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

new to QT and I am planning to display images aligning beautifully with layouts.

I create 3 Qlabels and group them in vertical and horizontal layouts to construct a widget like:

```
<layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
<item>
 <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
  <item>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </item>
  <item>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </item>
 </layout>
</item>
<item>
 <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
  <property name="text">
   <string>TextLabel</string>
  </property>
 </widget>
</item>
```

in designer:

I use following to load my images and display images:

```
 ui->setupUi(this);
src=cv::imread("image2.bmp");
cvtColor(src,src,CV_BGR2RGB);
img = QImage((const unsigned char*)(src.data),src.cols,src.rows,src.cols*src.channels(),QImage::Format_RGB888);

ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img).scaled(ui->label->width(), ui->label->height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));

ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img).scaled(ui->label_2->width(), ui->label_2->height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));

ui->label_3->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img).scaled(ui->label_3->width(), ui->label_3->height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
```

displaying image spans 480*640, and I choose to keep the aspect ratio.
however, the program runs like this:
pic lays in [screen shots here](http://app.yinxiang.com/shard/s5/sh/a3d3f1be-e6e9-4051-bf78-5955aebfbe18/7d406b79a4601b5059f20d7c81399ac2)

the image is resizing in a surprisingly wrong way. I have try `Qt::KeepAspectRatiobyExpanding` and `Qt::ignoreAspectRatio` but none of these behavior as expect.

Any idea about this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the wrong way"? Also the images are white/blank (or is it just me?)

Comment: the issue come from the fact that the label size might have bogus values when you are executing the `setPixmap` instructions, and the label is only re-sized later. I'll bet Merlin069 option along with `ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img))` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the image to fill the label with: -

```
void QLabel::setScaledContents(bool)
```

So call: -

```
ui->label->setScaledContents(true);
ui->label_2->setScaledContents(true);
ui->label_3->setScaledContents(true);
```

Also note that you can set the pixmap in the designer. Just add the images as a resource, then set it on the label, in its properties: -

[image]

Comment: hi, it works! but seems to warp the image ignoring the aspect ratio and warps the label completely. is there any way to warp the label maximum and keep the aspect ratio?

Comment: Read the dimensions from the QPixmap and set the maximum width / height in the QLabel

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the images you've pasted, but perhaps the problem is based on the size of QLabels: what is their size prior to:

```
ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img).scaled(ui->label->width(), ui->label->height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
```

Perhaps it's very small or just enough to hold the "TextLabel" string, hence the weird resizing?

Comment: sad, I can't see the images I upload as well, alternatively, I upload them in other apps in the link. I am quite sure the Qlabels size is not that small, for instance, one of my labels geometrys in (1,1),215*171.

Comment: @flankechen you can post images directly on your question using the icon which look like an image frame.